# How can I add comma into existing value in DataFrame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, number-formatting

I scraped a DataFrame from one website but during scraping I lost comma in values, so it looks like below:

```
name   price 
x       100
y       89
z       123584
```

Now I have to modify values in column "price" by adding comma in each value on the second place counting by right. The result should be like this:

```
name   price 
x       1,00
y       0,89
z       1235,84
```

Do you have any ideas how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try using `str.replace` here:

```
df['price'] = df['price'].astype('str').str.replace(r'^(\d{2})$', '0\\1')
                                       .str.replace(r'^(\d+)(\d{2})$', '\\1,\\2')
```

The first call to `str.replace` prepends a leading zero for those prices consisting of only two (decimal) numbers.  The second call inserts a comma separator before the final two decimal digits.

Comment: Thanks for respond and help but I get in column "price" only NaN values. Perhaps I should add that values in columns price are "object" (I checked by using df.dtypes)

Comment: @Tmiskiewicz Try using `astype('str')` along with my same logic to first convert `price` to string.

Comment: Your answer also works :) and this hint with convert into string was key so thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

We can slice your string and add the commas:

```
df['price'].str[:-2] + ',' + df['price'].str[-2:]
```

```
0       1,00
1        ,89
2    1235,84
Name: price, dtype: object
```

---

Or we can use `str.cat` with the `sep` argument:

```
df['price'].str[:-2].str.cat(df['price'].str[-2:], sep=',')
```

```
0       1,00
1        ,89
2    1235,84
Name: price, dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks for help! I tried to use both your answers and it is very strange because it changed only parts of values in column and the rest of them are NaN. I can't see a pattern why it changed only part of values...

Comment: I got this. I changed a type of column into a string (after that I had to remove from string ".0" beacuse it somehow showed) and I used your first answer and it worked nice and smooth. Thanks for help :)